# patchvalue or setvalue of formbuilder does not mark field as dirty or touched

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have a multi-step form where the user traverses back and forth to the form. I save the form data in service and when he comes back I use patchValue to patch all the data to form. I tried setValue also, but the form fields are not marked as either dirty or touched. How do I mark fields updated as dirty and touched?

```
this.formBuilder.patchValue(formData);
```

Answer (score 23):

You could explicitly mark the form using `markAsDirty()` & `markAsTouched()` method over your form object. See [**API Here**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)

```
this.formName.markAsDirty()
this.formName.markAsTouched()
```

**Update**

Angular 8 onwards you can use `markAllAsTouched` to mark all form field as `touched`

```
this.formName.markAllAsTouched()
```

Comment: But this wont mark the field whose value got changed to dirty right?

Comment: I demonstrated form level dirty thing. You can do it on field level as well

Comment: I also came across this problem and despite being possible to use the methods that you referenced it seems like we shouldn't have to do it manually. My point is that would be good to have angular verifying if the new value is different from the old one and set the according flags automatically.

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado Only user interaction sets the dirty flag. This is intentional. See this discussion: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9768

Answer (score 7):

the only solution i found for this issue it's.

```
 this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      id:[null],
      name: ValidatorsUtil.name(),
      lastName: ValidatorsUtil.required(),
      email: ValidatorsUtil.email(),
      phone: ValidatorsUtil.required(),      
    });

this.form.setValue(this.client, {emitEvent: true});

Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach( controlKey => {
       this.form.controls[controlKey].markAsDirty();
     });
```